# How can I add class folders into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, compiler-construction, setting

Eclipse is set to compile to a build directory at 'bin'. I have a folder structure with various Java .class files (precompiled) which I want to copy into the folder 'bin' on compile.

How do I tell Eclipse to automatically do this?

Comment: What kind of project is it?  A web project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I include .class files in my project in Eclipse? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661110/how-do-i-include-class-files-in-my-project-in-eclipse-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'Add Class Folder...' and 'Add External Class Folder...' buttons under 'Java Build Path' in the project properties seem to do exactly what you want.