# Import class file into Java program?

Tags: java

I know this has been asked a few times, but I can't find a solution using those answers.

I have a class file called LRW.class which I have put in an folder called external in the eclipse folder under my program name. So my path to the class is: myusername.WorkBench.ProjectA.external.LRW.class and I've made that folder using the new class folder in eclipse.

How do I use/import/call this class in java?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the default package, being used by a class in the default package, you don't need to import it at all. If the class using `LRW` *isn't* in the default package, it would be easiest to put `LRW` *in* a package--you can't import classes in the default package (see [JLS section 7.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.5)).

If it complains it isn't found, you'll need to make sure that folder is listed in the project's build path (right-click project -> properties, Java build path, Libraries tab, Add Class Folder).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work still, I've tried setting the folder as a class folder and external class folder, they appear in the structure, but as soon as I type in import LRW; eclipse shows an error with no useful fix?

Comment: @EricBanderhide Is the class really there? Is the `LRW` class *really* in the default package, or did it have a `package` statement in it?

Comment: I don't fully understand, its just a class file I placed in a folder next to the src folder in its eclipse folder?

Comment: @EricBanderhide - I think you need to do a Java tutorial to learn what a package is in Java.  You shouldn't use SO as a way to avoid reading the textbook / tutorial.

Comment: @EricBanderhide I understand that, but a class has a package, either the default, or a named package. Your import must match the package of the class, and the class file must be located in a directory matching its package name. One way to determine what the package is to run `javap LRW` from the command line to see if it needs to go into a sub-directory under `external`.

Comment: @EricBanderhide That's just where it is in the folder; the *class file itself* was compiled either the default or a named package. Since your class is *also* in the default package (boooo) you don't even need to import it if it *was* compiled in the default package.

Comment: @EricBanderhide I pretty much already told you. *I* don't know anything about the LRW class other than what you've told me, and can't run `javap` on it to check. Try without the import. See if it's supposed to be in a package. Make sure the folder is listed correctly in the build dependencies (as a class folder). If *all* else fails, create a public git repo containing only the source and this single class file, in their current folder hierarchy, and provide a link to the project and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

it is correct, you  would use "import LRW" however it is a bad practice not to use namespaces. You should better put the class in a folder called , for example "com/mydomainn" and then  use

import com.mydomain.LRW

Answer (score 0):

Add `external` to your [build path as class folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965692/how-can-i-add-class-folders-into-eclipse) and use `LRW` like any other class.

Make sure `LRW` is in default package, otherwise you need to change it's location according to the package.