# how can i add .class files to my java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I include .class files in my project in Eclipse? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661110/how-do-i-include-class-files-in-my-project-in-eclipse-java)

I am using Eclipse for Java. I have a school assignment and I have to add some .class files to my project. how can i do this. and is there anything else that i have to do. I read somewhere i have to create some Interfaces. I am not sure. help me out you big guys

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project. Then go in "Properties".

Then click on "java build path".

The only way that i know to add class files is to add them as a .jar file by adding them to the "Librairies" list that you will find there.

If you do like that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To use .class files (if you have them) in a 'clean way', assemble them in a jar file (Java ARchive) and import that as a library. As soon as you do it, you get access to your classes easily.

If you want to get/see the implementation of .class files use **Java Decompiler**, and you can get it as a standalone GUI or as an eclipse plugin :

1. [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)
2. [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse)

Enjoy :)