# How to run a external .class file in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am taking a course on Coursera and as part of a quiz I am supposed to download their xyz.class and run it. I want to do it in eclipse as all of jar files are added in eclipse and I dont want to modify the class path of system as it is very untidy.

But I dont know how to run a external .class file through?Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to run it in Eclipse ?

> java classname

souhld do the trick. You can't use Eclipse to run an  external class file with a main method without creatin a java project with this class in its class path.

Comment: This would give `Error: Could not find or load main class classname.class`. '.class' should not be the part of that command ;)

Comment: @mtk oupssss Fixed ;-) To long since I manually entered a java command ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Right-click your Eclipse project, Build Path, Configure Build Path, Libraries, Add (External?) Class Folder.

Answer (score 1):

Just run

```
java xyz
```

eclipse might not required.

If you want to really work out through the eclipse then refer **[How do I include .class files in my project in Eclipse? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/661143/500725)** answer.

There is another way of approach without using eclipse.

Approach is by `creating a executable jar file` and by including all required libraries & `xyz.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the class file from the Package Explorer -> Run.

Answer (score 0):

goto file >> new project >> Import>> add executable jar files >> select your path where you have stored your .class files>> check include in work place

> > apply>> ok >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Done