# Cannot make eclipse read becker folder (which has classes in it)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, import

I have just started Object Oriented Programming, so I have very basic knowledge in programming and using IDEs. I am currently using Eclipse. I have got a project to make a robot do some specific tasks and to them i need to inherit classes from the becker folder. If i use another IDE such as JCreator or DocJava or ReadyToProgramWithJava, the IDE inherits the becker folder when i save the .java files in the same folder as the becker folder. 
i have already used the following code on the top of my program to import the classes
    "import becker.robots.*;" but it keeps saying that it cannot be resolved to a type.
I have tried to use this link to solve the problem 
 ([How do I include .class files in my project in Eclipse? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661110/how-do-i-include-class-files-in-my-project-in-eclipse-java)) but i failed to make the code work. It is possible that i might have done something wrong so i was wondering if someone could be me a step by step method so i can make my code inherit the class files from the folder "becker".
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Strip your project down to what you feel like sharing with the world (remove everything sensitive) and upload it to bitbucket.org or github so people can check it out and see the project structure.

Comment: are you asking me to upload the becker folder???

Comment: or just the project directory and files ?