# How can I run a java class as an applet in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I run a java class as an applet in Eclipse, I don't want to run the applet in a browser.

I just want to run it in Eclipse with **`AppletViewer`**. I have a .class file but it won't run.

Comment: `I have a .class file but it won't run.` -- How are you trying to run it?  What error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: I right click on the class file, go to "Run As", and there is no option to run it as an applet or application. If I hit the green arrow to run, nothing happens either.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you shouldn't try to interact directly with the generated files (such as .class files).  There's a reason that it hides them from you by default in the most views.

Instead find the .java file which contains the class which extends `Applet` and go into its "Run As" menu.  You should have the option to run it as a "Java Applet".

Comment: Oh okay, so there is no way to run just a class file (even on something other than Eclipse)? I don't have the java file.

Comment: Well, I suppose you can pull the .class file in as a resource (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661110/how-do-i-include-class-files-in-my-project-in-eclipse-java/661143#661143) and then write your own class which uses it and run *that*.  Keep in mind that eclipse is a compiler, it really expects you to have the source code, so things are going to be much more convoluted when you don't.